# SvcUtil vs WseWsdl3

Tags: c#, wsdl, stub, svcutil.exe, wse

Official [VmWare documentation](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.wssdk.dsg.doc%2Fsdk_c_sharp_development.5.5.html&path=7_1_0_0_2_3_1) describes how to use `WseWsdl3.exe` utility to generate csharp file `VimService.cs` from a set of `.wsdl` files:

> wsewsdl3.exe /n:Vim25Api /type:webClient /l:CS vim.wsdl vimService.wsdl

Since the package [Microsoft Web Services Enhancements (WSE) 3.0 for Microsoft .NET](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14089) is deprecated, what is an alternative to generate the same `VimService.cs` (supposedly, with the utility [SvcUtil.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx))?

---

The end goal is to create a self-contained script file which could generate final `Vim25Service.dll` without installing any old and unnecessary packages. The bad thing with `WseWsdl3.exe` is that it doesn't respect [the principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege), i.e. it looks up the path to a supporting `wsdl.exe` utility in the system registry, which makes `WseWsdl3.exe` unportable. Luckily `WseWsdl3.exe` is a .NET application and I could easily modify it myself, so that it takes the path to `wsdl.exe` as an argument, but, unfortunately, the license does not allow reverse engineering and especially recompilation of the program.

---

When I try to use `SvcUtil.exe` like that:

> SvcUtil.exe /language:cs vim.wsdl vimService.wsdl

`Error: Cannot import wsdl:portType`
`Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter`
`Error: There was a problem loading the XSD documents provided: a reference to a schema type with name 'DestroyPropertyFilterRequestType' and namespace 'urn:vim25' could not be resolved because the type definition could not be found in the schema for targetNamespace 'urn:vim25'. Please check the XSD documents provided and try again.`
`XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:vim25']/wsdl:portType[@name='VimPortType']`

Comment: Sorry for the bump, but could you consider to accept my answer? It solves the described problem and helps me hunting the necro badge here at SO.

Comment: @Yannic Sorry, but your answer didn't solve the problem. I know how to generate the file using wsdl.exe. The problem is that I wanted to use SvcUtil.exe instead.

Comment: Okay, have you solved the problem by yourself in the meantime? I had exactly the same problem and just used ``wsdl`` instead since it works as expected. I know that the docs state ``SvcUtil`` but there are many blogs posts suggesting the use of ``wsdl``.

Answer (score 1):

Use `wsdl` to generate the C# file.

```
wsdl /n:Vim25Api /o:VimService.cs vim.wsdl vimService.wsdl
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(v=vs.100).aspx